# How does WebApplication.CreateBuilder().Services.AddTransient() work in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using an ASP.NET Core MVC web application. I have a model called `District`:

```
public class DistrictModel
{
    public int district_id { get; set; }
    public string district_name { get; set; }
}
```

I have two data sources for districts, one is test data I have in a JSON file and the other production data in a SQL Server database.

In order to make it easy to switch between the data sources (I believe this is called dependency inversion?) I created an interface to define the functions for getting data:

```
public interface IDistrictServices
{
    List<DistrictModel> GetAllDistricts();
    DistrictModel GetDistrictByID(int district_id);
    List<DistrictModel> SearchDistricts(string search_term);
}
```

And I used the interface for both the classes for retrieving JSON and SQL.

JSON class:

```
public class DistrictJSON : IDistrictServices
{
    public List<DistrictModel> GetAllDistricts()
    {
        string district_file_location = @"wwwroot/data/districts.json"; //move this to config
        string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(district_file_location);
        List<DistrictModel> found_districts = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<DistrictModel>>(jsonString);
        return found_districts;
    }
}
```

SQL Server class:

```
public class DistrictSQL : IDistrictServices
{
    //move connection string to config
    string connection_string = @"Data Source=SWSQLDEV001;User ID=thannah;Password=*****;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;Database=CapV3;"; 

    public List<DistrictModel> GetAllDistricts()
    {
        List<DistrictModel> found_districts = new List<DistrictModel>();

        string sql_statement = @"
            SELECT dd.id, dd.fullname
            FROM districtdim dd
            INNER JOIN versions v ON v.districtid = dd.id
            WHERE v.version = 'Current Forecast' ";

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connection_string))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand (sql_statement, connection);

            try
            {
                connection.Open ();

                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    found_districts.Add(new DistrictModel { district_id = (int)reader[0], district_name = (string)reader[1] });
                }
            } 
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        return found_districts;
    }
}
```

My controller gets all the districts and sends them to a view for display:

```
public class DistrictController : Controller
{
    public IDistrictServices districtlist { get; set; }

    public DistrictController(IDistrictServices dataservice) 
    {
        districtlist = dataservice;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(districtlist.GetAllDistricts()) ;
    }
}
```

`Program.cs` defines which service is used, JSON or SQL Server:

```
using OperationalForecast.Services;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddTransient<IDistrictServices, DistrictSQL>();
//builder.Services.AddTransient<IDistrictServices, DistrictJSON>();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

These were the two lines of code I added:

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<IDistrictServices, DistrictSQL>();
//builder.Services.AddTransient<IDistrictServices, DistrictJSON>();
```

Whichever line I leave uncommented is the class that is used. If I leave both lines uncommented, the second line gets used.

Here's my question: how does this actually work? At some point the `DistrictController` constructor is called (I assume every time the `/District` url is used? Or only once per session?). How can this code know I intend the specified class to be for the `District` controller and not some other controller? What if I have multiple interfaces and need to pass multiple interfaces to the controller?

This part seems like PFM and I'm worried if I don't really understand how it works I won't be able to complete my application.

Comment: AddTransient adds a ServiceDescriptor to the service collection. When ASP.NET Core creates your controller to serve the request, it also checks what dependencies it needs. The latest registration wins, so the second one is created and provided to the controller constructor. If you want both, you need to request `IEnumerable<IDistrictServices>` in your controller constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can this code know I intend the specified class to be for the District controller and not some other controller?

It doesn't.

Every time the service provider needs to instantiate your District controller (or any other type that requires `IDistrictServices` for that matter), it will inject a new `DistrictSQL` instance, because that's what you told it to do here:

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<IDistrictServices, DistrictSQL>();
```

If different controllers need different implementations, you would need to use a different service type (or use some factory to resolve the implementation type at runtime).

---

> At some point the DistrictController constructor is called (I assume every time the /District url is used? Or only once per session?)

Controller constructors are called once per HTTP request.

They are registered as *scoped* serviced by this extension method:

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
```

The service provider creates a new scope for each HTTP request, so a single controller instance will be resolved to handle the request.

---

> What if I have multiple interfaces and need to pass multiple interfaces to the controller?

Then you would register those types with the service provider as well, in the same way you did for `IDistrictServices`.

Note that you can control the lifespan of the service:

- Transient = new instance each time the dependency is required.
- Scoped = reuse a single instance for the duration of a service scope (equivalent to a HTTP request in ASP.Net).
- Singleton = reuse a single instance for the lifetime of the application.

Answer (score 1):

> I believe this is called dependency inversion?

*Dependency Injection*, more specifically.

> how does this actually work? At some point the DistrictController constructor is called (I assume every time the /District url is used? Or only once per session?). How can this code know I intend the specified class to be for the District controller and not some other controller?

It doesn't. The statement `builder.Services.AddTransient<IDistrictServices, DistrictSQL>();` says that *every time* any class requires an `IDistrictServices` instance via its constructor, it will get an `DistrictSQL` instance.

Since `Services` was configured with `AddTransient`, a *new* `DistrictSQL` object will be created every time.

> What if I have multiple interfaces and need to pass multiple interfaces to the controller?

This is possible. Just declare them as constructor parameters, and make sure to register the mapping between interface and implementation like you did here.

IIRC, the official [ASP.NET Dependency Injection documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection) is fairly comprehensive, so you may want to look at it.

Comment: To rephrase to ensure I understand. Every time a class is initiated, if the constructor requires a class or interface that is not explicitly provided during the instantiation (e.g. "new DistrictSQL()" instead of "new DistrictSQL(new Connection())" if the DistrictSQL class requires a Connection object), the framework will look for services in the builder and use a matching service to provide what the constructor needs? Assuming the matching service was provided, of course.

Comment: @TristenHannah If you call a constructor in code, nothing special happens. If you write code like `new DistrictSQL()` and the constructor really requires a `Connection` object, the code isn't going to compile. Dependency Injection only works if you let it.

Comment: I see. I misinterpreted how I wrote something,. I thought I called a constructor explicitly but in reality I chained dependencies.